# How to handle SAML v2 response using OpenSAML in RestEasy service

Tags: java, saml, resteasy

I have read about how SAML v2 is working from this [link](https://blog.surf.nl/en/saml-for-dummies/). I see that I require an Assertion Consumer Service URL that will receive the SAML v2 response.

Currently, the URL I provide is a RESTEasy endpoint developed using Java and deployed on Tomcat. Assuming the SAML v2 response will be received at this endpoint, what method type should I provide my endpoint (GET or POST) and also what should it consume (XML or JSON)

What should be the logic inside the endpoint to parse the SAML v2 response. I am aware of using OpenSAML in Java but can that be used in my case as well?

My Java code looks like follows

```
@POST
@Path("/getDetails")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public Response getDetails(String xml,@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization){
      //how to consume and decrypt SAML response over here?
    return Response.status(Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_OK).entity(Constants.DATA_OK).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually specify whether your assertion consumer service URL will be post or redirect(GET) in your metadata.

In your metadata, you provide the below tag:

```
 <AssertionConsumerService
            index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/Consumer/metaAlias/sp"/>
```

It should accept XML as SAML v2 response will be in XML in particular format.

Also you can use onelogin saml API,

https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml

To understand example request and response you can use the below link:
https://www.samltool.com/online_tools.php

For opensaml you can get an example code from the below link and with the help of it, you can have your own implementation
http://www.capcourse.com/Library/OpenSAML/index.html

Comment: hi Pooja, thanks for your reply. I have a question. when it hits my endpoint how will I get the assertion token. Also I have a mobile app and I need to send this assertion token back to mobile app.

Comment: You need to write the whole logic on your own or you can take help from the github project I have mentioned.

Comment: ok got it. also how will I send my token back to mobile app. Basically my flow is like..mobile app opens login page in in app browser.. mobile based in cordova based application. User enters credentials and clicks login. On submit, IDP sends SAML response to ACS. After that I need to send only the token and the required attributes to mobile app..so how will it be done

Comment: I don't know exactly the correct way to do it but you can use a work around. After getting attributes from XML Response, save them in a static json or may be in database and then have another API exposed to return these attributes.

Comment: pooja one more question. is this URL ==> https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/Consumer/metaAlias/sp  ..your public hosted server endpoint?

Comment: Sorry no idea about that I will search and let you know

Comment: hello Pooja. I have edited my question can be please assist

Comment: Hi pooja. Thanks. I get an idea. However this is my exact requirement I need to obtain a token (SAML assertion) from the SAML response. So can you please tell me where in the SAML response can we find this token ? Do you have any example ? Can you please share your email address I will explain to you in detail what I am currently doing please ? Appreciate your help and response

Comment: If you are looking for attributes which will contain information of user or depends upon IDP, you need to check saml:AttributeStatement tag and if you want to have assertion then you can get the ID attribute from saml:Assertion tag. All of these you can find from the link i have shared of saml tool. You need to go through the examples of request and response from that link.

Comment: Hi Pooja, Yes about attributes it's clear to me how to get those. For token (SAML assertion) do you mean that the ID attribute from saml:Assertion tag is the token ? Are you sure about this? Because I don't if you have heard of JWT tokens which are also sent as a part of the attributes that can be used to validate user information

Comment: For example in this link ==> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0 , are you saying that "b07b804c-7c29-ea16-7300-4f3d6f7928ac" is the token ?

Comment: See every idp has different response attributes. So it completely depends upon your idp. I have told you the tags to look for. Now you either talk to your idp or get the sample response.